# R: superscript on geom_vline label

Tags: r, ggplot2, label

Title says it all: I want to use superscript on the label of a vertical line in ggplot. 
Here's a less than beautiful example:

```
df <- data.frame(x = c(1:10),y = c(2,2,3,4,5,5,6,7,5,4))

ggplot(data=df, aes(x,y, group=1)) +
  geom_line() +
  scale_x_reverse() +
  geom_vline(xintercept=3) +
  geom_text(aes(x=3, label=paste("3400","cm","^-1", sep=""), y=5), angle=90, vjust = 1.2)
```

I want the -1 superscripted. There are numerous solutions around to do this on plot axes labels, but none of them work here. Can someone help?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're so close! You just need to set `parse=TRUE` in `geom_text` and use `?plotmath` syntax.

```
df <- data.frame(x = c(1:10),y = c(2,2,3,4,5,5,6,7,5,4))

library(ggplot2)
ggplot(data=df, aes(x,y, group=1)) +
  geom_line() +
  scale_x_reverse() +
  geom_vline(xintercept=3) +
  #geom_text(data = data.frame(x = 3, y = 5), label = paste("paste(3400, cm)","^-1", sep=""), 
  #  angle=90, parse = TRUE, vjust = 1.2) + 
  annotate("text", x = 3, y = 5, angle = 90, label = paste("paste(3400, cm)","^-1", sep=""), 
    vjust = 1.2, parse = TRUE)
```

Result:

[image]

Also, notice that the text is less blurry than in your code. This is because your code is actually printing the label 10 times at the same coordinates. You would need to make `geom_text` use different data or better yet, use `annotate`

Comment: @Chrisss Thank you so much!